# How can I implement doubly linked lists into my tree structure in Python?

Tags: python, data-structures, tree

So I'm trying to represent an XML file using python. I already managed to do that. But each child node in my tree has to be doubly linked and I don't know how to do that. I've found a few examples of code online but they all use classes and the professor doesn't want us using classes. Here's my code:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree


def create_tree(): #This function creates the root element of my tree
    n = input("Enter your root Element: ")
    root = Element(n)
    tree = ElementTree(root)
    print(etree.tostring(root))
    return root

def add_child():
    root = create_tree()
    new = True
    while new == True:
        ask = input("If you wish to add a new child type 'yes', else type something else: ")
        if ask == 'yes':
            n = input("Enter the name of the node: ") #This block of code creates a child and appends it to the root element
            node = Element(n)
            root.append(node)
            print(etree.tostring(root))
        else:
            break
    return etree.tostring(root)
add_child()
```

For those of you wondering, the purpose of this project is to create a rooted tree with unbounded branching. I hope that once I can implement the doubly linked list I will be able to add a child node within a child node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to implement a linked list using lists.  You can define
each element as a list with the element itself, the item before it, and the item after it.  If the list contains the previous node, the next node, and the element itself, respectively, and the head is stored in `head`, the syntax to append `newElement` to the beginning of the list would be as follows:

```
newNode = [None,head,newElement]
head[0] = newNode
head = newNode
```